# How do I extend the Django Group model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Is there a way to extend the built-in Django Group object to add additional attributes similar to the way you can extend a user object? With a user object, you can do the following:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

and add the following to the settings.py file

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'app.UserProfile'
```

which gets you:

```
profile = User.objects.get(id=1).get_profile()
```

Is there any equivalent to this approach for extending a group? If not, is there an alternative approach I can take?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can create a model that subclasses Group, add your own fields, and use a Model Manager to return any custom querysets you need. Here's a truncated example showing how I extended Group to represent Families associated with a school:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, User

class FamilyManager(models.Manager):
    """
    Lets us do querysets limited to families that have 
    currently enrolled students, e.g.:
        Family.has_students.all() 
    """
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(FamilyManager, self).get_query_set().filter(student__enrolled=True).distinct()


class Family(Group):
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True)

    # Two managers for this model - the first is default 
    # (so all families appear in the admin).
    # The second is only invoked when we call 
    # Family.has_students.all()  
    objects = models.Manager()
    has_students = FamilyManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Families"
        ordering = ['name']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: While this may work if group model is created from the beginning of the project this answer incomplete because it does not address the non trivial issue with migration of existing group data.

Comment: @RomanKonoval The answer is not incomplete because it answers the question that was asked. Migrating data is a completely different topic.

Comment: How would anyone access to Family instance a user is a part of with a setup like this? Doing something similar, but user.groups only gets the Group instances. I would love to be able to do something like user.families. Is there a related name Django sets up by default to access the families from user?

Answer (score 58):

If you simply subclass the Group object then by default it will create a new database table and the admin site won't pick up any new fields.

You need to inject new fields into the existing Group:

```
if not hasattr(Group, 'parent'):
    field = models.ForeignKey(Group, blank=True, null=True, related_name='children')
    field.contribute_to_class(Group, 'parent')
```

To add methods to the Group, subclass but tag the model as proxy:

```
class MyGroup(Group):

    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def myFunction(self):
        return True
```

Comment: Where does the 'if not hasattr(Group...' line go?

Comment: You can place it in models.py above MyGroup

Comment: Does this approach still work with Django migrations? 1.8 will create a migration just fine for the injected fields, but puts it into the Django pip folder where it is not found on re-building.

Comment: @beluga.me You can move migrations using `MIGRATION_MODULES`, does that work?

Comment: How to if I need more fields in my Group model, like email ?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with migrations. it says "No changes detected in app"

Comment: Be careful with this answer as it adds a migration file into : django.contrib.auth.migrations.    I haven't found a way to avoid that

Comment: anyone found a way to avoid migration added to django.contrib.auth.migrations? The issue I am facing with this is my migrations are broken and now I have to manually fix it. But as the migrations are in auth.migrations I am unable to edit them. Any way around for that?

Answer (score 12):

I managed to use migrations with @Semprini aswer.

So i needed to create a company related field in my groups related field, so in my models i did this:

```
if not hasattr(Group, 'company'):
    field = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)
    field.contribute_to_class(Group, 'company')


class Group(Group):

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

Then i run manage.py makemigrations. This created 2 files. One with dependencies on the other, but the first one belonging to  the `auth` app was created inside my virtual enviroment. The files look like this:

```
# Generated by Django 2.2.5 on 2019-10-08 16:00

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('myapp', '0013_guestuser_permissions_20190919_1715'),
        ('auth', '0011_update_proxy_permissions'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='group',
            name='company',
            field=models.ForeignKey(
                null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.DO_NOTHING, to='myapp.Company'),
        ),
    ]
```

The second one created in myapp migrations folder look like this:

```
# Generated by Django 2.2.5 on 2019-10-08 16:00

import django.contrib.auth.models
from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('auth', '0012_group_company_20191008'),
        ('myapp', '0013_guestuser_permissions_20190919_1715'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Group',
            fields=[
            ],
            options={
                'proxy': True,
                'indexes': [],
                'constraints': [],
            },
            bases=('auth.group',),
            managers=[
                ('objects', django.contrib.auth.models.GroupManager()),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

So the solution was to move the file created in my virtualenv to myapp migrations folder, before the other one generated with makemigrations, but since the migration is applied to the `auth` app instead of `myapp` i have to implement a workaround in the file. So the final file now is:

```
# Generated by Django 2.2.5 on 2019-10-08 16:00

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('myapp', '0013_guestuser_permissions_20190919_1715'),
        ('auth', '0011_update_proxy_permissions'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='group',
            name='company',
            field=models.ForeignKey(
                null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.DO_NOTHING, to='myapp.Company'),
        ),
    ]

    def mutate_state(self, project_state, preserve=True):
        """
        This is a workaround that allows to store ``auth``
        migration outside the directory it should be stored.
        """
        app_label = self.app_label
        self.app_label = 'auth'
        state = super(Migration, self).mutate_state(project_state, preserve)
        self.app_label = app_label
        return state

    def apply(self, project_state, schema_editor, collect_sql=False):
        """
        Same workaround as described in ``mutate_state`` method.
        """
        app_label = self.app_label
        self.app_label = 'auth'
        state = super(Migration, self).apply(project_state, schema_editor, collect_sql)
        self.app_label = app_label
        return state
```

The mutate an apply methods allow you to migrate to the `auth` app from `myapp` migrations.

In the second file i just change the dependencie to depend on the newly file created:

```
# Generated by Django 2.2.5 on 2019-10-08 16:00

import django.contrib.auth.models
from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('myapp', '0014_group_company_20191008'),
        ('myapp', '0013_guestuser_permissions_20190919_1715'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Group',
            fields=[
            ],
            options={
                'proxy': True,
                'indexes': [],
                'constraints': [],
            },
            bases=('auth.group',),
            managers=[
                ('objects', django.contrib.auth.models.GroupManager()),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: `class Group(Group):` oh! man

Answer (score 10):

For me worked solution based on:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/pl/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-user

Let me explain what I did with Groups extending default model with email alias:

First of all I created my own django application let name it

> python manage.py startapp **auth_custom**

Code section:

In *auth_custom/models.py* I created object **CustomGroup**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.db import models

class CustomGroup(models.Model):
        """
        Overwrites original Django Group.
        """
        def __str__(self):
            return "{}".format(self.group.name)

        group = models.OneToOneField('auth.Group', unique=True)
        email_alias = models.EmailField(max_length=70, blank=True, default="")
```

In *auth_custom/admin.py*:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import GroupAdmin as BaseGroupAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group


class GroupInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = CustomGroup
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'custom groups'


class GroupAdmin(BaseGroupAdmin):
    inlines = (GroupInline, )


# Re-register GroupAdmin
admin.site.unregister(Group)
admin.site.register(Group, GroupAdmin)
```

After making migrations I have such result in Django Admin view.

[Custom Group in Django Admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgJD0.png)

In order to access this custom field you must type:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group


    group = Group.objects.get(name="Admins")  # example name

    email_alias = group.customgroup.email_alias
```

If any mistakes please notify me, I'll correct this answere.

Comment: not working for me, geting error when adding a group from django admin interface. ```TypeError at /admin/staff/customgroup/add/
__str__ returned non-string (type Group)```

Comment: I suggest you to copy everything into separate `auth_custom/` directory as I showed and then verify if error still occurs. I suppose that your file hierarchy differs and something more can be missed. Sorry for late response, I am not really often here.

Comment: Its been a month now, Thanks for the reply. I have fixed it by some other approach I guess. dont remember now...!

Comment: And how do i create an instance in views?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [django-group-model](https://pypi.org/project/django-group-model/) package to override the Group model the way you would do with the User model. Here's a short example.

Install the package

```bash
pip install django-group-model
```

Add it to your installed apps towards the top.

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django_group_model',
    ...
]
```

After installing, we'll override the default Group model, call it Roles, and add a category field as a custom field (optional).

```py
from django_group_model.models import AbstractGroup


class Role(AbstractGroup):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "role"
        verbose_name_plual = "roles"
```

Set the `AUTH_GROUP_MODEL` setting.

```py
AUTH_GROUP_MODEL = 'myapp.Role'
```

Use the group model with your User model

```py
class User(AbstractUser, ...):
    ...
    roles = models.ManyToManyField(
        'myapp.Role',
        blank=True,
        related_name="user_set",
        related_query_name="user",
    )
    groups = None
    ...
```

**Don't forget to set the default `groups` to `None`**

You may want to also go through the documentation [here](https://github.com/ankitchhatbar/django-group-model)