# Django: permissions based on property of model instance

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Assume that I have the following models:

```
from django.db import models


class Environment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)


class Device(models.Model):
    # (some other fields)
    environment = models.ForeignKey(Environment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

There are also two "permission levels":

- `root`: users with this level can edit and delete `Devices`
- `regular_user`: users with this level can view `Devices`

Each user for specified `Environment` should have either `root` or `regular_user` permission level, ie. in environment A he can be `root` and in environment B - `regular_user`.

For specifying that user has a certain permission level for selected environment, I use the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12893442) (`<permission_level_name>:<environment_id>`, eg.: `root:1`). This can be a subject to change if it will help to resolve the problem.

User accesses data via Django REST Framework-based API.

**How to prevent user with `root` permission level in environment A to edit (via API) `Devices` that are in environment B, where he has `regular_user` permission level?**

Solutions like `django-guardian` allow to assign permissions per `Device` instance and Django Permissions allow to assign permissions per Model but what I am looking for is permission system based on property of `Device` instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to solve your problem with [dry-rest-permissions](https://github.com/dbkaplan/dry-rest-permissions) It allows for fine grained control over permissions, actions etc

Example:

```
class Device(models.Model):
        # (some other fields)
        environment = models.ForeignKey(Environment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        def has_object_write_permission(self, request):
            return self.environment.is_root(request.user)
```

Comment: It looks like this solution is perfect for the problem, thank you!