# How to extend Django Group and still use in Django User

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am looking to extend the functionality of Django's group, so I can have extra properties on the Group such as a url for the Group's homepage. Something like this:

```
class Organization(Group):
  url = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

However when using this organization and adding it to a user (by using `org.user_set.add(user)`) I have no way of accessing the url field from the User. When I do `user.groups.all()` it shows the user is in a Group (not Organization) with the same name I set on my organization `org`. So how I do I add functionality to Group but keep it accessible from my user info?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181039/how-do-i-extend-the-django-group-model

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two option;

1) New model;

```
class GroupProfile(models.Model):
    group = models.OneToOneField('auth.Group', unique=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

2) Monkey Patch;

```
Group.add_to_class('url', models.CharField(max_length=100))
```

In second option you have to use app like `south` for db migration.