# Django: Rename Group to Role

Tags: django, django-admin, django-authentication

I'm required to use the word "Role" instead of "Group" in a Django project.

I tried i18n, but could make `auth` pick up the translation.

I also tried replacing `django.contrib.auth` with a `myaqpp.auth` where `Group` is called ``Role.

Which is the correct way to do this renaming?

Comment: These are related Q&As:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294832/how-to-extend-django-group-and-still-use-in-django-user

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181039/how-do-i-extend-the-django-group-model

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it just a question of displaying `Role` in the admin interface, instead of `Group`? In that case, you could easily create a proxy model:

model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class Role(Group):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        app_label = 'auth'
        verbose_name = _('Role')
```

and then unregister the default `Group` model from the `GroupAdmin` and register your `Role` model instead:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import GroupAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

from .models import Role


admin.site.unregister(Group)
admin.site.register(Role, GroupAdmin)
```

With all that said, I'd question the business decision forcing you to implement such a silly thing.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The only think that is missing is that the inline form from the User model still  shows as Group.