# How can I tell django 1.7 to put migration into specific folder

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

I'm running into quite interesting situation.

I need to extend default django's Group model with some fields.
I tried to use inheritance first, e.g. inherit from Group model and change some references, but seems I can't change all needed references, so, this way completely breaks django permission system.

Then I found this answer: [How do I extend the Django Group model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181039/how-do-i-extend-the-django-group-model) where guy suggested to use `field.contribute_to_class()` method.

I have put this adjustment right above the model definition in < myapp >. (don't ask me why do I need roles for group, it's not my idea, I just need them :D)

```
if not hasattr(Group, 'roles'):
    field = models.ManyToManyField(
        Role, verbose_name=_('roles'), blank=True,
        help_text=_('List of roles attached to this group'),
           related_name='groups')
    field.contribute_to_class(Group, 'roles')


class MyGroup(Group):

    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def _sync_permissions(self):
        """
            This method will sync group permissions with all attached Roles.
        """
        self.permissions.clear()
        for role in self.roles.all():
            self.permissions.add(role.permissions)
        self.save()
```

This part seems to be working (it really modifies django.contrib.auth.models.Group model)

But what I need next is to generate a migration for the Group model.
If I simply run `./manage.py makemigrations <myapp>` it generates a migration for Group model, but tries to put it inside django.contrib.auth application, that is definitely not what I need.

So, my question here is:

Is there a way to tell django to generate a migration for Group model, but not to create a migration file under python libs directory, but rather create it inside < myapp > or just output the migration code?

Comment: Seems that another possible solution for this particular case is to define m2m between Group and Role on a Role side. This way migration will be created for role and reverse relation will be automatically added to Group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the location where django looks for migrations cn be custominzed using [MIGRATION_MODULES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#migration-modules) in your settings.py, anyway this   means that ALL the migrations (not only the new) must be there. 
You need to copy the original migrations and manually update them when you upgrade Django

You can create a dedicated package so to not clash with your migrations
Es.

```
MIGRATION_MODULES = {
     'django.contrib.auth' : 'myapp.auth_migrations',
     'myapp': 'myapp.migrations'  # this line is only to clarify. IT'S NOT NEEDED AT ALL 
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I'll have to copy all existing migrations from 'auth' to my new app and... they will clash with app's own migrations :(
But anyways, I'll try to do something with this tomorrow.
Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen the `field.contribute_to_class()` to class solution to this problem before.

For me it looks a bit dirty, like monkey patching.

You would go back and use a 1:1 relation to `Group,` or inherit from `Group`.

You say that you can't change all needed references to Group? What is missing?

I know this is not an answer to your question, but maybe a solution to your problem :-)

Comment: First problem I've encountered with inheritance, was the fact that I had to change User.groups relation to point to my new group. Django does not allow redefining fields in inherited Models (I had to redefine AbstractUser.groups), I had to copy A LOT of base models just to modify one field.
But then it appeared that reverse relation called 'group' is hardcoded in some places, like https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/backends.py#L29 . This actually means I have to copy the whole backend to modify this... I what's then remains unchanged from original django auth?