# How to remove Group and Permission models from Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I want to create my own Group and Permission model. However, Django has its built-in models for this which are giving me naming conflicts on it's own model`Group`. I know you can deregister to remove it from this admin, but this does not help me.

What is best here?

Is it possible to use Django's own and models for Groups and add to them (i.e add more fields), or can I remove the built-in Group model altogether?

My user seems to extend from `AbstractBaseUser`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use Django's `Group` and `Permission`, maybe you don't want to use django.contrib.auth at all? If that is the case, simply remove `django.contrib.auth` from `INSTALLED_APPS`.

However, I want to point out that I can't really think of a usecase where this would make sense. You have to have a really good reason for writing your own `Group` and `Permission`

Comment: I need to add more fields to Group this is my only reason.

Comment: So in that case, you are probably looking for **extending** the models rather than removing them? See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181039/how-do-i-extend-the-django-group-model) on extending `Group` model.

Answer (score 1):

from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, User

```
class CustomGroup(Group):
     new_attr = ...

class UserGroup(User):
    new_attr = ...
```

You can also use [Proxy Models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#proxy-models)