# django - is it possible to abstract the auth_group model?

Tags: django

I know it's possible to do something like the following:

```
class EnterpassUser(AbstractUser):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    is_application = models.BooleanField(default=False, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'enterpassuser'
        managed = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Which allows me to use the `auth_user` model and create a unique `enterpassuser` model to replace it.

I'd like to do something similar with the group model however every option I come across forces me to keep the table name as `auth_group` and `auth_group_permissions` where I'd like it to maintain the same process flow as creating a custom user model.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I extend the Django Group model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181039/how-do-i-extend-the-django-group-model)