# django model creates extra table for same relation

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am having an issue with django model that creates multiple tables for same class, it creates two table for same relation, it should create 3 table i.e `users`, `groups`, and `user_groups` but I having an extra table with name `users_groups` (note: an extra 's').

Seems an issue with `verbose_name`, `db_meta` or `related_name`

**Full Code:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Define a model manager for User model with no username field."""
    pass

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    """Model representing a User with some extended fields and email as username field"""
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['email']
        db_table = 'users'
    
    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
        return self.email

class Group(models.Model):
    """Model representing a Group"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, through='UserGroup', related_name='user_groups')
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
        db_table = 'groups'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class UserGroup(models.Model):
    """Model representing a User's Group"""
    
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name = 'group')
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name = 'user')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user_groups'
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug this to see where this table comes from, or what's using it? Perhaps looking through the migrations file(s) to see what tables are being created etc may help debugging.

Comment: I've tried to delete all the migrations/ folder and database table, then generated. That's also created the duplicate table

Comment: Yes, but if you read the migration, look at what's being created for the `users_groups` table, you may figure out why it's being created. You've not detailed it here, so we can only speculate as to what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`django.contrib.auth`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/), provide a [`Group`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/models.py) model which is not an abstract model.

When you create your `CustomUser`, it's inherit `AbstractUser` which contain a [`groups`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L245) field, creating a many to many relation to the `django.contrib.auth.Group` model. So the `user_groups` table is created to handle the relation between `CustomUser` and `django.contrib.auth.Group` models. By default, the table name for a many to many relation concatenate table names of relation parts ([`_get_m2m_db_table`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L1565)).

In order the customize the Group model, take a look at [How do I extend the Django Group model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181039/how-do-i-extend-the-django-group-model)