# How to make django file changes that can reflect it on the main server

Tags: python, django, server, project, django-migrations

I have made a change in the django default auth model template. I have added a new column in existing default auth table.

So from my project's models.py, I have made change in the django auth model which is present in **django.contrib.auth.models.py**

So now the changes are stored in migrations file which is present in my local file as contrib.auth/migration folder is present locally.

Now the problem is it is reflecting correctly on my local pc once make migrations and migrate cmds are executed, but when I want to export the code, ofcourse this migration file will not be pushed, and the main server does not run this 2 cmds as it reads it automatically from migration files to avoid any future loss so how do I put it on the main server so that it can be implemented and people can start seeing the change.

Thank You

The only thing is server does not run any cmds like makemigrations and migrate and also manually storing file at particular location doesn't help either.

Comment: `ofcourse this migration file will not be pushed` The standard Django workflow is that migrations are tracked in source control. Are you including migrations in git/whatever source control you're using?

Comment: I am using gitlab and as long as the migration files are within the project's folder, they are pushed in gitlab but this contrib.auth.models.py makes migration file in the django local path folder so there's no way I can add that.

Answer (score 1):

You should never make changes to the packages themselves. Instead, you should import their class, method, etc. and override them in your local project files.

Let's say you will make changes to the user model, you will import the user class and override it:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    # your changes goes here
```

Then later refer to this overwritten class instead of the original class.

Check the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project) for this particular case.

Comment: I want to add a new row in the default django auth model so I wrote a code in my project's models.py by importing Group from django.contrib.auth.models so now running makemigrations and migrate cmds generate migration file in the django.contrib.auth file path which is local so can't push it in gitlab, do you have any other alternative for that

Comment: Same applies for group. Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181039/how-do-i-extend-the-django-group-model will help.